# Consolidating two Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I want to consolidate two worksheets on the basis of a "Register No." in a third worksheet.

```
Workbook:
Tabelle1: Consolidated Worksheet //
Tabelle2: Input Data1 //
Tabelle3: Input Data2
```

***Notes:***

- At first the "Register No." can only be found in Tabelle2 & Tabelle3 in column A.
- Because Tabelle1 has also a different column sequence than Tabelle2 & Tabelle3 I am using vLookup to paste the data to the right columns in Tabelle1.

***Idea:***

**1. Step**
Pasting Tabelle2 Data, including "Register No.", to the right columns in Tabelle1 via vLookup. *Note:* This means "Register No." to Tabelle 1 column A.

**2. Step**
Pasting Tabelle3 Data to right **rows** and columns in Tabelle1 via vLookup.
As Tabelle3 contains more "Register No." than Tabelle2, I want my code to check the "Register No." in Tabelle1 column A and copy the corresponding data from Tabelle3.

**ERROR**:

The **2. Step** is not working.

> Runtime-Error '1004'

For example:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow2

    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange2, 2, False)

Next i
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? Thanks a lot :)

**My Code:**

```
Sub ConsolidateData()


Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Tabelle2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrange = Tabelle2.UsedRange


For i = 2 To lastrow
    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 1, False)
Next i

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 2, False)
Next i



For i = 2 To lastrow
Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 3, False)
Next i


Dim lastrow2 As Long
lastrow2 = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrange2 = Tabelle3.UsedRange

For i = 2 To lastrow2
    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange2, 2, False)
Next i

For i = 2 To lastrow2
    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange2, 3, False)
Next i

For i = 2 To lastrow2
    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange2, 4, False)
Next i

For i = 2 To lastrow2
    Tabelle1.Cells(7 + i, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange2, 5, False)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to include the specific error you are getting.

Comment: @braX : Thanks! I have just edited it :)

Comment: "*The 2. Step is not working.*" is no error description nor a error message. Please be more specific. Reading [ask] might help to improve your question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Hope it is better now :)

Comment: @HPM And what is the message? And in which line does the error occur?

Comment: Is this the full error?: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you are referencing your worksheets.  You are using the Worksheet.CodeName vs the Worksheet.Name of the worksheet.

Look at my example below and you will see that the Worksheet.CodeName and Worksheet.Name do not match.

[image]

Worksheet.CodeName is the 1st part of the name and Worksheet.Name is what's shown in parentheses.  Therefore the Worksheet.CodeName for the second worksheet is Sheet5, whereas the Worksheet.Name is Sheet6.

This is because I deleted a worksheet and excel, behind the scenes, renamed the Worksheet.CodeName reference.

To use what you see when looking at the tabs in the workbook you need to reference it by Worksheet.Name, not Worksheet.CodeName.

```
Sub testPickingWorksheets()

' This code fails
    a = Sheet6.Range("A1").Value
    MsgBox (a)

' This code works
    a = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").Value
    MsgBox (a)

End Sub
```

As you can see from the code above, you need to use the Worksheets() Ojbect with the Worksheet.Name in "quotes" instead of directly referencing the Worksheet.CodeName.