# Consolidating two sheets

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I do have two different sheets (Tabelle2 & Tabelle3) and I want to consolidate them  in a third one (Tabelle1) on basis of the Register No.

To copy Tabelle2 into the correct columns in Tabelle1 I'm using VLookup which is working smooth.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Tabelle2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrange = Tabelle2.UsedRange


For i = 2 To lastrow
    Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 1, False)
Next i

 For i = 2 To lastrow
    Tabelle1.Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 2, False)
Next i

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Tabelle1.Cells(i, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 3, False)
Next i
```

In a 2. Step I want my code to check the "Register No." in Tabelle1 and copy only those rows from  Tabelle3 to Tabelle1. *Note: Tabelle3 is containing many more "Register No." which data I don't need*

Does anyone know which function to use or how to solve this challange? :)

[image]

Comment: "In a 2. Step I want my code to check the "Register No." in Tabelle1 and copy only those rows from Tabelle3 to Tabelle1." - which rows?

Comment: So tabelle 1 already has register no's in it and you only want the data from tabelle 2 and 3 which match these?

Comment: If you run down each row in 'Tabelle 2', then you can use `WorksheetFunction.Match` to check if the item is in 'Tabelle 3'.  For example, `lRow=0:On Error Resume Next:lRow=WorksheetFunction.Match("Value", Sheet1.Columns(1),0):On Error GoTo 0` will set `lRow` to the row in Column **A** of Sheet1 that contains "Value", or `0` if "Value" does not exist in Column **A** of `Sheet1`

Comment: Why exactly are you using `VLookup` to copy from `Tabelle2` to `Tabelle1`? It is searching for the same row, where you index `i` is already in. So its better to use one `For`-Loop and copy the columns with `.Cells(i, column)`. To Perfom the copy process from  `Tabelle3`, you can use a `VLookup`.

Comment: (Also, this looks very much like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260060/consolidating-two-worksheets)?  It is much better written and easier to understand, but you should probably have [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49260060/edit) that question instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myrange = Tabelle3.UsedRange


    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Tabelle1.Cells(i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 2, False)
    Next i

     For i = 2 To lastrow
        Tabelle1.Cells(i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 3, False)
    Next i

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Tabelle1.Cells(i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle1.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 4, False)
    Next i
```

Comment: why the 3 loops when you could use one?

Comment: yes but here I just used OP's code for this answer.

Comment: :-) I have used that answer myself too in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maddy :) Funny thing is I still think my code, I used before, is the same as yours but somehow yours works. (So probably not so similiar at the end :D )

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it really simple - put the three tables on the same worksheet like this:

[image]

The idea would be to get something like this, after running the code below:

[image]

Probably the simplest way to achieve it with some bad practices as hard-coding is like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt             As Long
    Dim combinedIndex   As Range
    Dim currentCell     As Range

    With Worksheets(1)
        Set combinedIndex = .Range("A7:A12")

        'Fill table with names
        For cnt = 2 To 5
            Set currentCell = Nothing
            Set currentCell = combinedIndex.Find(Cells(cnt, 1))
            If Not currentCell Is Nothing Then
                currentCell.Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(cnt, 2)
            End If
        Next cnt

        'Fill table with Shoe Sizes
        For cnt = 2 To 5
            Set currentCell = Nothing
            Set currentCell = combinedIndex.Find(Cells(cnt, 4))
            If Not currentCell Is Nothing Then
                currentCell.Offset(0, 2) = .Cells(cnt, 5)
            End If
        Next cnt
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what the code does:

- Defines the `combinedIndex` range. In a more general case it can be `Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")`
- then loops through the table with the names. It is hardcoded from 2 to 5, but it can be loosened up a bit. Once a `RegisterN` is found, the second value is written to the offset of the found value
- the same is for the Shoe Sizes table

Comment: How on earth did you translate the question? Bravo

Comment: @QHarr - :) thanks - in general this is a one of the standard cases when someone is using Excel as a database.